# How to reduce copying resources time for running code?

Tags: maven, automation, maven-surefire-plugin

I have used JAVA for framework coding.Copying resources taking more time for running code (almost 6 to 7 min). I am running my code using maven command

> mvn clean compile test.

I am using below pom.xml for dependency management.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>framework</groupId>
<artifactId>framework</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jre.level>1.8</jre.level>
    <jdk.level>1.8</jdk.level>
</properties>

<build>
    <!-- Source directory configuration -->
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>


        <!-- Following plugin executes the testng tests -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <printSummary>true</printSummary>
                <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                <suiteXmlFiles>

                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    <!-- <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile> -->
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
        <version>v3-rev72-1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ru.yandex.qatools.ashot/ashot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
        <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.javafaker/javafaker -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
        <version>0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.seratch/jslack -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.seratch</groupId>
        <artifactId>jslack</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

how to reduce the time for execution? 
Please let me know any other information required.

Comment: Follow conventions over configuration and remove the configuration `<sourceDirectory>..</sourceDirectory>` just keep the defaults. BTW: How many files do you have in resources directory ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `mvn clean compile test` than your running parts double etc. It is sufficient just to run `mvn clean test`. In this `compile` phase is included.
See more details in the [build life cycle documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).